# one authentication prompt for multiple web applications in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, authentication, windows-authentication

Currently, I am getting the credential prompt for each web applications. I want only one authentication prompt to authenticate multiple web application.

E.g

```
Application 1 - my.intranet.com
Application 2 - portal.intranet.com
Application 3 - collaboration.intranet.com
```

I am referencing Application 2 and 3 on the home page of application

So it asks credential three times. but my requirement is that It should prompt for credential only once.

Comment: What authentication mechanism do you (want to) use? Windows Integrated? FBA? Where's you users' DB (AD, SQL...)?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

1. If your users log into their machines with domain credentials, you can add *.intranet.com to the Local Intranet Zone in IE. This will work for IE and Chrome, but not Firefox.
2. You can implement a Single Sign On service. ADFS 3.0 provides this functionality, and can be used in conjunction with Web Application Proxy. With ADFS 3.0, you do not need to convert your Web Application to SAML. There are other SSO services out there, such as Ping, as well. Note that WAP does not work with wildcard domains (e.g. SharePoint Addins). This is corrected in Windows Server 2016.